# C code hanging at scanf() statement

Tags: c, arrays, loops, scanf, freeze

I am trying to get input into an array, until a user enters -1 to exit the input mode.

Something strange is happening in this block of code when a -1 is entered but only after at least two values have been entered.

```
#define ARRAYSIZE 100
int input[ARRAYSIZE];
int i=0;
do {
  printf("Enter data #%d or -1 to exit: ", i);
  scanf("%d", &input[i]);
} while(input[i++] != -1 && i<ARRAYSIZE)
```

The code will just hang indefinitely. I have compiled and run on two separate architectures, but the problem doesn't show up when it is run in gdb.

Inserting print statements revealed that the code is indeed hanging at the scanf statement.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Uh, did it still hang after you hit "enter"?  Is "input[]" declared to be an integer array with one or more "int" elements?  Is "i" initialized to 0 before you enter the loop?

Comment: Yes, thank you I have edited the question to make that clear

Comment: What is entry ? Why not just `input[i++]!=-1` as an exit check ?

Comment: Do you have all the necessary `#include` lines?

Comment: try putting `return 0;` after the loop

Comment: AshRj, I have updated the question, the result when it is run is the same.

Comment: Now the test condition checks for the character just after the character you have entered. `i++` is done before the check.

Comment: You should be using a `do .... while` loop in this case as the `input` array is not initialized to some value other than -1.

Comment: Please post a complete program that we can compile. If this code snippet is part of a much larger program, the problem might not lie with the scanf as you so believe. In that case you should try writing a smaller program using the same concept to see if it still hangs.

Comment: Why did you completely change the code? The question no longer makes sense. The code you have now will not exhibit the behavior you describe. Please, don't create fake and meaningless questions by randomly changing their isolated parts.

Comment: A previous version of the code was incorrect, but this version now runs correctly for me. Are you still having the same problem?

Comment: @Luke Walsh - please change the code back to the original broken version, so that it can be a learning tool for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were never checking the value of the data you saved (it was check the next uninitialized element), do while is a better fit

```
#define ARRAYSIZE 100
int input[ARRAYSIZE],i=0;
do {printf("Enter data #%d or -1 to exit: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);
}while(input[i] != -1 && ++i<ARRAYSIZE);
//if this is main() you need a return 0; here also or it will hang
```

Comment: +1 You beat me with seconds.. was about to post the same logic.

Comment: @sansix probably because I saved time forgetting to put the -ing on the second checking :)

Answer (score 0):

My questions:

3) Is "i" initialized to 0 before you enter the loop?

2) Is "input[]" declared to be an integer array with one or more "int" elements?

... and ...

1) Did it still hang after you hit "enter"?

If you're not already aware of it, you *must* hit "enter" before scanf() will process *any* input.

SUGGESTION:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE 100

int 
main ()
{
  int input[ARRAYSIZE];
  int i=0;
  int entry=0;
  while(entry != -1 && i<ARRAYSIZE) {
    printf("Enter data #%d or -1 to exit: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);
    entry = input[i];
    fprintf (stderr, "entry= %d, input[i]= %d...\n", entry, input[i]);
    i++;
  }
  printf ("Done.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Note the "fprintf(stderr)".

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
Enter data #0 or -1 to exit: 300
entry= 300, input[i]= 300...
Enter data #1 or -1 to exit: -1
entry= -1, input[i]= -1...
Done.
```

Again - please clarify whether or not you're using the "Enter" key.  And if so, please let us know your platform (e.g. Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc).

'Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Your code depends on the values of uninitialized array elements. No wonder it behaves irrationally.

In the condition of your `while` cycle you compare `input[i]` with `-1`. At each and every iteration `input[i]` is not initialized - it contains a garbage value. Since a garbage value is rather unlikely to be equal to `-1`, your cycle keeps running and running, stopping every time at `scanf` to wait for input. This creates an illusion of "hanging at `scanf`", while in reality the `scanf` itself has nothing to do with the real problem.

Of course, the real issue here is not that the array is uninitialized, but rather that your cycle condition checks the *wrong* array element. You probably intended to check the most recently entered element. Instead you check the next element. Why?

I'd say that your intent calls for a cycle with *post* condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable to check for -1. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE 10

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int data[ARRAYSIZE];
    int input = 0;
    int i = 0;     

    while(input != -1 && i < ARRAYSIZE) {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        data[i] = input;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```